# ASP.NET model that requires a reference to a IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a model `Blueprint` that requires a reference to an IdentityUser. When I run `Add-Migration CreateBlueprintSchema` the following error is thrown:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Blueprint'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'author' in 'Blueprint(IdentityUser author, string name, string data)'.

How do I resolve this issue?

Blueprint.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace FactorioStudio.Models
{
    public class Blueprint
    {
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Data { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IdentityUser Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public Blueprint? ParentBlueprint { get; set; }

        public Blueprint(IdentityUser author, string name, string data)
        {
            Author = author;
            Name = name;
            Data = data;
            CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            string hashSource = Author.Id +
                Name +
                CreationDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
                Data;

            using SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashSource));
            string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
            Id = hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors _EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor_

Answer (score 0):

change your model like this:

```
public class Blueprint
    {
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Data { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IdentityUser Author { get; set; } = new IdentityUser();

        //.......
   }
```

**or** just add a `non-parameter constructor` in your model.

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors);

**Edit=======================**

For testing convenience, I manually added a foreign key(If I don't add Fk by myself, EF core will create `shadow foreign key property`, But i can't use it directly), Then I create a Blueprint without referring to an existing IdentityUser, You can see it will report a SqlException that show error in FK.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Daniel, If my answer help you solve your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks you very much.

Comment: But would this not create a new user? Instead Author should refer to an existing user and a Blueprint must not be created without referring to an existing (no new) user.

Comment: Yes, If you choose to use the first method, You can create a Blueprint without referring to an existing IdentityUser, But when you choose to use the second method I provided( just add a non-parameter constructor in your model), A Blueprint must not be created without referring to an existing IdentityUser, I have edited my answer,  you can see my test results in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, EF Core cannot set navigation properties using a constructor. Instead, use a [custom value generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.valuegenerator?view=efcore-6.0) to create the hash for the ID when saving the entity.

```cs
    public class BlueprintHashGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
    {
        public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

        public override string Next(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is not Blueprint bp)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected entity");
            }

            string hashSource = bp.Author.Id +
                bp.Name +
                bp.CreationDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
                bp.Data;

            using SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashSource));
            return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
        }
    }
```

then in model builder

```cs
builder.Entity<Blueprint>().Property(bp => bp.Id).HasValueGenerator<BlueprintHashGenerator>().ValueGeneratedNever();
```

It will generate the value on `SaveChanges`, so ensure all properties are set before calling save (`Author`, `Name`, `CreationDate`, `Data`).